# What is happening when using the keyword this in lambdas vs functions with Typescript

Tags: javascript, lambda, typescript, angular

I am using Typescript for an Angular 2 project. I notice that when we use the keyword `this` inside a labmda expression vs a function, `this` refers to different things.

For example, let's say I have an Angular component like the following.

```
export class MyComponet {
 isActive = true;
 names = [ "john", "jeff", "jared" ];

 doSomethingWithLambda() {
  names.forEach( (value, index) => {
   if(this.isActive) { //this.isActive refers to MyComponent.isActive
    //do something...
   }
  });
 }

 doSomethingWithFunction() {
  names.forEach( function(value, index) {
   if(this.isActive) { //this.isActive is undefined, since this refers to the function
    //do something
   }
  });
 }

 doSomethingWithFunction2() {
  let isActive = this.isActive;
  names.forEach( function(value, index) {
   if(isActive) { //if we change isActive will this also change MyComponent.isActive?
    //do something
   }
  });
 }
}
```

What is really happening here (behind the scene, so to speak)? What's the magic behind `this` inside a lambda that makes it able to "correctly" refer to the outer class' fields? I understand `this` inside a function will refer to the function itself.

Also, I have a `doSomethingWithFunction2` method that will reference `MyComponent.isActive` into a local variable. If I change that local variable, that should be like changing the one it references, right? (regardless of it being a "primitive" like integer/number or an "object" like JSON { })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fat-arrow function syntax is shorthand for:

```
function () { }.bind(this);
```

`bind` is a Javascript ES5 method equivalent to this:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function bind(context) {
  var func = this;
  return function () {
    return func.apply(context, arguments);
  };
}
```

In regards to

> Also, I have a doSomethingWithFunction2 method that will reference MyComponent.isActive into a local variable. If I change that local variable, that should be like changing the one it references, right? (regardless of it being a "primitive" like integer/number or an "object" like JSON { })

In Javascript, variables are like pointers and except for some limited cases (primitives and copy-on-write objects) will change the referenced value when mutated.  Reassigning will not change the original value, e.g. `isActive = false;` but `this.isActive = false` would in fact re-assign the variable `isActive` on `this` which is now hopefully correctly assigned.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how [lambda function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are implement in TS. this in arrow function is lexically inferred so it more in line with below code

function Person() {
  var self = this; // Some choose `that` instead of `self`. 
                   // Choose one and be consistent.
  self.age = 0;

setInterval(function growUp() {
    // The callback refers to the `self` variable of which
    // the value is the expected object.
    self.age++;
  }, 1000);
}
So inside the lambda  function it is not actually this but a context closer self. This may not be actual implementation but much closer to give you understanding of what is happening.

Now when you are outside the my impotent `this` refers to global var which would be `window`

The lambda function is similar to javascripts [bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

**Protip** see your transpiled JS how your lambda function is transforming.